# iOS 7: call screen background photo bugged?

Tags: iphone, contacts, ios, call

During a call to any contact, on call screen is displaying hard blurred image. This image is a user photo attached to its contact in address book. The issue is, that this photo is SAME on EVERY contact I call, no matter is there set photo on contact or not.

I have tryed to remove this image from contact it belongs to, but that doesn't do the trick, it still appear in ANY contact I called.

Any solution to remove or change this image?

Comment: I occasionally have the same problem - a reboot fixes it though… try rebooting :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I occasionally have the same problem, usually only after I decline a call by pressing the lock button. A reboot fixes it though… try rebooting!